# jQuery mobile upgrading 1.1.1 to 1.4.3 causes 403 errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been using jQuery Mobile v1.1.1 with jQuery v1.7.1 for quite some time now, but am doing some major overhauls and need to upgrade. So I have been trying to swap to jQm v1.4.3 and jQuery v1.11.1.

However the first page loads, which is kind of like a log-in form. But where submit used to work, it now prompts the error loading page dialog, and when you look in the console the error is a 403 permission denied error - any idea's where I should start looking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Every time I see a title like "XYZ causes 403 errors," I think to myself, "Can't you narrow it down to just one or two errors?"

Comment: You need to go though every line in your scripts and html and rewrite as there have been many changes since v.1 and most methods have  depreciated -- http://jquerymobile.com/upgrade-guide/1.4/